# How to display the items from one column being in a relation with items from another column? Lotus Notes

Tags: view, field, lotus-notes

My view "Relations" contains 2 columns, let say: X and Y. For all the Xi, from X, where i = 1,n; n - number of entries, I have:

```
Xi ... Y1
   ... Y2
   ... Y3 
 ........
```

So, one item from X can have associate many values from Y. The field correspondent for Y ( called 'user' ) is a dialog list which have: use formula for choices:

```
_view := "Relations";

@Unique ( @DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; _view ; numbers ; 2 ) )
```

What I want to do is: When in the first field called 'numbers' I add a item that exists in the 1st column of view
to APPEAR AUTOMATICALLY in the FIELD called 'user' the FIRST VALUE that corresponds on the Y column for X.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I understand your question now.  I thought you were asking about how to get the view set up correctly, but I see that is wrong.

Your default value formula field for user should be

```
@Subset( @Unique ( @DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; _view ; numbers ; 2 ) ); 1);
```

You can use a hidden field if you want, using just the formula from your question.  then you would reference the hiddenFeld in the value list formula, and in the default value formula you would do this:

```
 @Subset(hiddenField;1)
```

Using the hidden field will improve performance because the lookup will only be done once.

**Previous answer**

*There's a column property called "Show multiple values as separate entries" which you can apply to the "Y" column.  There's a good [blog entry](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/multiple-values-in-multiple-rows-in-multiple-columns) on IBM's DeveloperWorks site that shows how the option works.*

Comment: Well, I thought I must add some code to a hide computed field. And then the name of this field should be in the default value of the 'user' field.